# Display Encrypted and decrypted Message on Client Console Window

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have WCF hello service. I am able to encrypt and decrypt the messages. I want to display encrypyted and decrypted message on client console window

Answer (score 1):

[Console.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) and [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) are your friends.